# priority queue comparator not called for all the elements in the linked list

Tags: c++, priority-queue

I'm working on merging K linked list using pq. But the comparator not working for all the elements in the Linked list. someone please shed the light why the comparator not working as expected.

This code works if all the linked list has only one node. Not sure why the comparator not working for next node.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<queue>
using namespace std;
class ListNode {
    public:
        int val;
        ListNode *next;
        ListNode() {
            this->val = 0;
            this->next = nullptr;
        }
        ListNode(int x) {
            this->val = x;
            this->next = nullptr;
        }
        
        ListNode(int x, ListNode *next):val(x),next(next) {
        }
};

class Solution {
public:
    struct cmp {
        bool operator()(ListNode *a, ListNode *b) {
            return a->val > b->val;
        }
    };
    ListNode* mergeKLists(vector<ListNode*>& lists) {
        priority_queue<ListNode *, vector<ListNode*>, cmp> pq;
        ListNode *dummy = new ListNode(0);
        ListNode *cur = dummy;
        ListNode *top;
        for (int i=0; i< lists.size(); i++) {
        pq.push(lists[i]);
    }
    while(!pq.empty()) {
            top = pq.top();
        pq.pop();
            cur->next = top;
            cur = cur->next;
        cur->next = nullptr;
            if(top->next != nullptr) {
                pq.push(top->next);
            }
        }
        return dummy->next;
    }
};

int main() {
    Solution obj;
    ListNode *a = new ListNode(9);
    a->next = new ListNode(34);
    a->next->next = new ListNode(55);   
    ListNode *b = new ListNode(45);
    b->next = new ListNode(4);
    b->next->next = new ListNode(5);
    vector<ListNode*> Lists;
    Lists.push_back(a);
    Lists.push_back(b);
    ListNode *result = obj.mergeKLists(Lists);
    while(result != nullptr) {
        cout<<result->val<< " ";
        result = result->next;
    }
    cout<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
9 34 45 4 5 55
```

Comment: First advise, stop doing leetcode puzzles and learn more C++ first . And do that using a local development environment and a debugger. (Note that leetcode isn't even using std::list, which should show you they have no interest in C++, just in the algorithms you produce). Also your code is leaking memory

Comment: Are you always using this kind of confusing intendation in your code? No? Then please be considerate of the people you're asking for help and ensure the code you post doesn't have these kinds of issues that are entirely unrelated to the actual problem.

Comment: Your algorithm assumes that each list passed to it is already sorted. But one of the lists you are passing is not in fact sorted.